# Dynamic OnClick Button Event

Tags: javascript, onclick, dynamic-data

I have a table that is created dynamically, and I want to put an EDIT / DELETE buttons with onclick events in each row.

However, I don't know how to make them unique with the row's id and then make an onclick event for each so I can update/delete the values from the row.

I tried:

```
<INPUT TYPE='BUTTON' NAME='EDIT_PRODUCT_FROM_SEARCH' ID=".$row['alpha_p_ID']." VALUE='Delete'>
```

But I don't know how to tell the event:

```
$('what to write here?').click(function() {

});
```

EDIT:

The creation of button works but the onclick event don't. Code below:

PHP button code

```
results_table = "<table cellspacing='0' style='border: 1px solid #405D99'><tr bgcolor='#405D99' style='color: white'><th>Main Image</th><th>Gallery Image 1</th><th>Gallery Image 2</th><th>Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Manufacturer</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price-Wholesale</th><th>Price-Retail</th><th>Options</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
$results_table .= "<tr>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee'><a href='products/".$row['alpha_p_imglink_main']."' rel='lightbox'><img src='products/".$row['alpha_p_imglink_main']."' width='150px' height='150px'; border='0'/></a></td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee'><a href='products/".$row['alpha_p_imglink_gal1']."' rel='lightbox'><img src='products/".$row['alpha_p_imglink_gal1']."' width='150px' height='150px'; border='0'/></a></td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee'><a href='products/".$row['alpha_p_imglink_gal2']."' rel='lightbox'><img src='products/".$row['alpha_p_imglink_gal2']."' width='150px' height='150px'; border='0'/></a></td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee' align='center'>$row[alpha_p_name_en]</td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee' align='center'>$row[alpha_p_type]</td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee' align='center'>$row[alpha_p_firm_owner]</td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee' align='center'>$row[alpha_p_quantity]</td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee' align='center'>$row[alpha_p_price_wholesale]</td>";
$results_table .= "<td bgcolor='#dfe3ee' align='center'>$row[alpha_p_price_retail]</td>";
$results_table .= "<td colspan='1' rowspan='1' bgcolor='#f7f7f7' align='center'>";
$results_table .= "<a href='#' NAME='EDIT_PRODUCT_FROM_SEARCH' ID=".$row['alpha_p_ID']." CLASS='EDIT_BUTTON_CLASS'>Edit</a>";
$results_table .= "<a href='#' NAME='DEL_PRODUCT_FROM_SEARCH' ID=".$row['alpha_p_ID']." CLASS='DELETE_BUTTON_CLASS'>Delete</a>";
$results_table .= "</tr>";
}
echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$results_table .="</table>";
echo $results_table;
```

Onclick:

```
                        $('.EDIT_BUTTON_CLASS').on("click", function(event) {
                    var e_id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var p_edit_id = $('input[name=P_NAME_EDIT]');
                    (p_edit_id).val(e_id);
                    alert("aaa");
                    });
```

The onclick event should fill in a textbox with the id and post an alert.

Comment: Writing html tags and attributes capitalized is outdated as far as I know. Instead of creating multiple functions create one function that will handle your object, that was clicked: `function test(obj)`. and in `input` add `onclick="test(this)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to change

```
<INPUT TYPE='BUTTON' NAME='EDIT_PRODUCT_FROM_SEARCH' ID="'.$row['alpha_p_ID'].'" VALUE='Delete'>
```

to

```
echo '<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" NAME="EDIT_PRODUCT_FROM_SEARCH" ID=".$row['alpha_p_ID']." 
onclick="your_js_delete_function('.$row['alpha_p_ID'].');" VALUE="Delete">'
```

then in JS

```
function yourj_s_delete_function(id) {
  //do something
  // you could also id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

You could also assign a class so that your

```
$('what to write here?').click(function() {

});
```

becomes

```
$('.delete_button').click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   .... rest of the code
});
```

Note: if your `$row['alpha_p_id']` returns a numeric value it's a good practice a add a string value as a prefix as numbers only ID would cause markup validation to fail

So you would change `ID="'.$row['alpha_p_ID'].'"` to `ID="btn_'.$row['alpha_p_ID'].'"`

and you'd need to change

```
var id_str = $(this).attr('id');
var id=id_str.split("_", 1);
```

**UPDATE**

As you mentioned that these buttons are created dynamically - you'll need to use `on()` method instead of `click -

```
$('.delete_button').on("click", function(event){
    alert("I am clicked!");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. Awesome, gonna try it out. Thank you. 

And the button code I posted was from a php do while loop, I just didn't understand the id part so I didn't post the php code. Still thanks for clarifying it

Comment: I am not sure if its working, I put an alert just to test and no alert is showing. I tried with just a button with alert, no alert. Alert doesn't work from buttons created dynamically?

Comment: If it's dynamically generated button - then try as I mentioned above in the Update.

Comment: I think the event doesn't work because the buttons are created in a while loop. That is the only thing holding my logic for now. If that's not it, I can't find anything else.

The test button on same page works with any code, the dynamic button doesn't like any code, not even if it passes a static value as id.

I have no solution to this

Comment: If you post your code where these buttons are being generated I'll look.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the event to all `input[type="button"]` and then get the ID value from another attribute. For example:

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    $id = $(this).id;
    $action = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I see. But that is a solution using global "all buttons" not locally per button.

Comment: I believe it's way better to have a single event handler for many elements: the main benefit of this is that you're independent of HTML. If you add more buttons at a later stage, there is no need to assign new handlers; the event handler will know automatically that there is a new button to do things with.

Comment: I agree with you on having less to deal with more, but in this case I need to prioritize the use of buttons locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's attr() method to access the ID of the element that generated the event.

```
<input class='mybutton' type='button' name='edit_product_from_search' id=".$row['alpha_p_id']." value='delete'>
```

and in jQuery code:

```
$('.mybutton').click(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

$(this) in jQuery refers to the element that generated the event.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the input a class you can then use the selector

```
var buttons = $('.classname');
```

With this array of buttons you should be able to do:

```
$.each(buttons, function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
         // Click event here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<?php print $row['alpha_p_ID'] ?>").click(function() {

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Or add attribute **class="delete"** to the button

```
<INPUT TYPE='BUTTON' NAME='EDIT_PRODUCT_FROM_SEARCH' ID=".$row['alpha_p_ID']." class="delete" VALUE='Delete'>
```

And then

```
$('.delete').click(function(){
  id = $(this).attr('ID');

  // delete code goes here...

});
```